# distance between y-axis and label

Tags: gnuplot

What is wrong with this?

```
set ylabel 1.0,0.0
set ylabel "{/:Italic M}" font "Allert,12"
```

The error is

```
 unexpected or unrecognized token
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It would help to make your question a little more explicit about what you intend to do.

Guessing from your code, possibly you want to have italic `M` label with an offset of `(1,0)`. This would write

```
set ylabel "{/:Italic M}" font "Allert,12" offset 1,0
```

Indeed the first number in `offset` will set the distance between y-axis and label. What you were missing is simply this `offset` keyword in the first line :

```
set ylabel offset 1.0,0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
gnuplot>?set xlabel

 Syntax:
       set xlabel {"<label>"} {offset <offset>} {font "<font>{,<size>}"}
                  {textcolor <colorspec>} {{no}enhanced}
                  {rotate by <degrees> | rotate parallel | norotate}
       show xlabel
```

It seems you cannot give `x,y` positions to the labels. What you can do is give it `dx,dy` offsets:

```
> set ylabel "{/:Italic M}" font "Allert,12" offset dx,dy
```

Hope this helps.